# Unable to direct to another view controller using alert action

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, storyboard, alert

I want the user to be directed to another view controller when the OK button is clicked in the appearing alert action. User has to be directed when the OK button is clicked, not immediately when this alert is shown. Here is what I tried:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Succesful", message: "Successfully added!", preferredStyle: .alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
self.present(alert, animated: true)
let uivc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FourthViewController")
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(uivc, animated: true)
```

The app does not crash but it does not also direct to my other view controller when the OK button is clicked. How can I fix this issue?

I'd be very glad if someone can help me out!

Edit: I believe my question got misunderstood, so I tried to explain things more clearly, sorry for my bad english.

Comment: The error message says it all.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, check the StoryboardId of your view controller and change it to "FourthViewController".

Comment: Please [search on the error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+Storyboard+doesn%27t+contain+a+view+controller+with+identifier).

Comment: Make sure you have added same view controller with an identifier "FourthViewController"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the so called "FourthViewController" in your storyboard, and set the identifier to that - this is different than the name, so it might be confusing. I've attached a screenshot, hope it helps!

[image]

and the actions you want carried by the alert need to be handled by the "handler", usually I prefer putting that in it's own method, but for simplicity, the following will work for your case :

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Succesful", message: "Successfully added!", preferredStyle: .alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { _ in
    let uivc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FourthViewController")
    self.navigationController!.pushViewController(uivc, animated: true)
}))
self.present(alert, animated: true)
```

Comment: thank you for your response! Having entered the identity, the app does not crash now, it runs without crashing. However, the app does not direct to the other viewcontroller when the alert shows. Is there something I am missing about the code?

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work, I don't even see any alert showing up :(

Comment: sorry, added the last line...you still gotta present the alert lololol

Comment: Now the alert shows but when I click the OK button the app crashes and I get this error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidPathValidation', reason: '(child:) Must be a non-empty string and not contain '.' '#' '$' '[' or ']''. Sorry a lot for taking your time I just want to fix this problem :(

Comment: that might be an issue in the screen you are navigating to...what does the viewDidLoad() of that new view controller have in it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179522/discussion-between-bobby-dickson-and-unis-barakat).

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Make sure you are calling correct nib file
> 2. Make sure you set storyboard id in storyboard .